# Writing data to a file

Tags: java, android

I want to create a folder from inside my app. Inside the folder, I want to create just one file (say *recents*) where the app will keep writing data line by line on each launch.

```
private void saveForRecents(String phoneNumber) {
    //Need to open File and write the phonenumbers that has been passed into it
    try{    
        File mydir = getDir("recents", 0); 

        //Creating an internal dir;
        File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "recents"); 

        //Getting a file within the dir.
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileWithinMyDir.getAbsoluteFile());


        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(phoneNumber);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to write into the file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

How do I access the contents of the *recents* file that is inside my directory *mydir*? And I want to access the data line by line as I'm writing data line by line. I would really appreciate if someone took their time to explain me how to do it because I need to learn it. Also please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You are using `getApplicationContext()` when you do not need it. Also, you are passing `Context.MODE_APPEND` to `getDir()`, which is not a supported value -- use `0`.

Comment: I need help with this. Can you please tell me why i dont need getApplicationContext? what i meant to say is why does it work without the context.

Comment: Also will this method write inside the same file or will it overwrite the contents of the file?? What i need to do is keep writing on the same file in a different line.

Comment: "what i meant to say is why does it work without the context" -- you need a `Context` in those places. You are already in a `Context`. Use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are doing, I think using SharedPreferences is a better way to go.  It won't be overwritten by someone else, and it's hidden from someone messing around in a file explorer.  Here's a quick example assuming you have your recent phone numbers in some sort of an array.  Other methods are possible of course.

```
SharedPreferences Prefs = getSharedPreferences("RecentPhoneNumbers", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor e = Prefs.edit();
e.clear();

for (String s : RecentPhoneArray)
{
   e.putString(s);
}
e.commit();
```

Then to load them the next time the application starts or needs a reload:

```
SharedPreferences Prefs = getSharedPreferences("RecentPhoneNumbers", MODE_PRIVATE);
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : Prefs.getAll().entrySet())
{
   String s = entry.getValue().toString();
   RecentPhoneArray.add(s);
}
```

Comment: Your answer contains incorrect information. SharedPreferences are just as "safe" as files contained within the app's private directory, which is what is being using by the user asking the question. Nobody else can "overwrite" those files, and nobody can poke around them using a file explorer, unless the phone is rooted -- but in that case, SharedPreferences are also accessible.

Comment: @323go You are correct, sorry. I had somehow misread that thinking the OP was making a directory somewhere accessible for anything like \sdcard

Comment: The problem is that I have to create two different folders and write a set of files inside one folder(each file also has set of data to be written inside it).(In this folder a new file is created everytime). Inside the other folder I have to create a file with data inside it.(In this folder data keeps getting added to the original file). Can you please suggest me the best way to do it as I am a complete novice when it comes to programming.

Comment: @nishan_vodoo The problem is that I don't know what you're saving and writing. Based on the OP, the best approach I would still consider to be the SharedPreferences. When you mention having multiple files and multiple folders, I would then start to think that maybe using SQL Lite is the way to go: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html.  It would allow saving and retrieving of data as you need. Now, if you know that you *for sure* need to read/write files, just Google code for that. You already seem to have some above!

Answer (score 0):

After a long time I figured out the second part of my problem. This might be useful for other users if they come across the same problem.

For Making a custom directory (here *recents*) and a custom file (here *recent*)

```
try
{
      File mydir = getDir("recents", 0); 
      File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "recent"); 
      //true here lets the data to be added in the same file in the next line
      // No value at all or a false will overwrite the file
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileWithinMyDir.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
      bw.write("Anything you want to write");
      bw.newLine();
      bw.flush();

    bw.close();

    }catch(Exception e){

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to write into the file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The following code helps to read the same file(here *recent*) inside the same directory(here *recents*)

```
try 
{

    File mydir = this.getDir("recents", 0);
    File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "recent");
    try 
    {
    // open the file for reading
    InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(fileWithinMyDir);


    if (instream != null)
    {
        // prepare the file for reading
        InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

        String line;

        while ((line = buffreader.readLine())!= null)
        {

        // do something with the line 

        }

        instream.close();
    }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
    // print stack trace.
    } 
    finally 
    {
    // close the file.

    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

One important thing to note is that if a directory ***recents*** here and file inside it ***recent*** here does not exist  then it will automatically be created in the first run. From the second run it will start referencing it rather than recreating the whole thing again...

**Hope this will help some users**